# Automatically compiling associated form resources (dfm) into a compiled resource (.res) when building a static library (.lib / .a) in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, static-linking, vcl, dfm

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell the C++Builder toolchain to automatically compile all of the associated resources (specifically form resources - DFM) into a .res when a **static library** is being built?

I used to use packages to "compartmentalize" my code in very large projects but recently I switched to using static libraries instead (due to persistent, long-standing issues with linking 64-bit code in packages - WRI123X and such) and one of the pain points with organizing my projects this way is, obviously, that static libraries (.lib / .a) only contain the code and not the resources.  This means that, at the executable project level, I have to maintain a list of link directories for each static library that contains forms data (instead of just referencing a single directory where all my .lib/.a files are placed).

What I would like to be able to do (in my static library project) is to tell the toolchain to compile BOTH the static library AND the associated form resources into my_lib.lib/a (code) file and my_lib.res (resource) file and put BOTH files into the designated "final output directory" for the static library (instead of deferring compilation of resources until the exe project).

Does anyone know if this is possible in C++Builder (as of 10.4.1) and, if so, how to go about it?

Thanks,

Marko